# How to install features in JBOSS FUSE?

Tags: jbossfuse, karaf, fabric8

I am able to check all the features using `features:list`

I wanted to install certain features in JBOSS Fuse, but the command

```
features:install camel-blueprint
```

is not working

I am getting error

```
    Error executing command: The container is managed by fabric, please use fabric:profile-edit --featur
es camel-blueprint/0.0.0 target-profile instead. See fabric:profile-edit --help for more information.
```

How can install the required features in JBOSS FUSE.

in JBOSSFUSE_HONE/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file I have entry called `featuresBoot` and added all the needed features to be loaded in startup

But, the status for all the features are uninstalled.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Fuse uses profiles (fabric) to define what to install on container, so you edit profiles, and then assign profile(s) to containers.

Frankly its easier to watch a few videos to get more familiar

- http://vimeo.com/album/2635012

For example the loan broker video is a good start.

If you do not want to use fabric, then you can install like old-school with manually commands like you do on Apache Karaf. But this requires you NOT to install fabric in JBoss Fuse.

Also there is the Red Hat JBoss Fuse documentation you can dive into (links to documentation from here)

- http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse

You can also find more details at the fabric8 project (community project of JBoss Fuse) documentation at:

- http://fabric8.io/#/site/book/doc/index.md?chapter=profiles_md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10357751)

Comment: @Vatine I can not agree with that. The question is answered quite clearly (either use fabric *or* karaf commands), and the links are only provided to expand OPs knowledge of the available options and how to use them properly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is that you have probably already set up this instance of JBoss Fuse / Fuse Fabric to be container managed, via `fabric:create`.

To "reset" your local installation (be careful! this deletes all containers and related configuration), run this command in cygwin to delete `data`, `instances` and `lock`:

```
cd /wherever/fabric8-karaf-1.0.0.redhat-412
$ rm -rf data instances lock
```

Now, when you restart Fuse, you should be able to install features directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the text below from the error messages. It should work.

"please use 'fabric:profile-edit --features camel-blueprint/0.0.0 target-profile'"